# Confirmation prompt for chmod, chown

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, chmod, chown

I'm just trying to add a confirmation prompt to a few linux commands like `chmod` and `chown`.

I've tried to google this but I can't find much information on the topic.

While searching I found out that there is a solution for `rm` using the `-i` option, though that can be overwritten with `-f`

However there is `safe-rm` package which you can install on your server which blacklists certain important directories which is quite a good solution, but sadly there is no similar package for `chmod` and `chown`.

So my ideal solution would be where `chmod` and `chown` have confirmation prompts and also certain directories are blacklisted from being chmod-ed and chown-ed.

Any answers much appreciated !!!

Comment: `chmod` and `chown` don't have confirmation switches because their effect are always reversible by root. There's no point in asking confirmation for an action that's reversible.

Comment: it's reversible but you can chown or chmod / and then if you don't know the exact permission, as there are quite a few files in there, you are lost

Comment: But still, the data wouldn't be lost, so it's still not as dangerous.

Comment: True but regardless of the data if the permissions and ownerships are not right many things on the server will be broken and repairing them isn't necessarily easy

Comment: Repairing them consists of either restoring a backup or using a backup to get a list of the permissions as they should be. And how to do that has been asked before.

Comment: It's still nice to avoid that altogether as restoring a backup takes time which means some downtime is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands [chown (1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) and [chmod (1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) do not natively have sunch an option. If you want to add that functionality then you either:

1. Have to change the source and recompile.
2. Or write a wrapper.

The first option is the cleanest. The second the easier. If you get stuck writing that then you need a new question which is likely a better fit for [SO], but briefly:

1) move chmod somewhere else. e.g. `mv /bin/chmod /bin/chmold.therealthing`

2) Create an executable script called chmod which does what you want (and which calls the real chmod).

Untested something from a non-shell script person (aka me:)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "/bin/chmod (Shell script) called with these arguments:"
echo $@

read -p "Are you sure you want to do this? (y/n) " RESPONSE
if [ "$RESPONSE" = "y" ]; then
    exec /bin/chmod.therealthing $@        
else
    echo "OK, aborting."
fi
```

if you want more granular control then the script rapidly becomes more complex.  Stiill, of you wish you could parse the input and execute a chmod for every file (after checking for a valid syntax).

Comment: Cheers for that, it seems like it's going to work : ), btw you've missed a double quote on the second line, also I'm trying to make this into a bash function but when I call it closes my shell, any chance you know why it's doing that?

Comment: Does it close only when you accept? I have an exec in there. (probably from my days when RAM was scarce).

Comment: Yep after accepting I just removed the exec actually and it sopped doing that : )

Answer (score 1):

A solution in bash would be to use shell functions and aliases.  You could put them in /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc if you only want them for specific users.  Here's some function and alias definitions you could use to do something like what you asked.

```
DANGERLIST=/etc/dangerous.paths

_dangerouspath() {
        file=$(readlink -e "$1")
        [ -z "${file}" ] && return 1

        while read pattern
        do
                [[ "${file}" =~ ^${pattern}$ ]] && return 0
        done < ${DANGERLIST}

        return 1
}

_checkpaths() {
        shift
        while [ -n "$1" ]
        do
                [[ "X$1" =~ ^X[^-].* ]] && _dangerouspath $1 && return 0
                shift
        done

        return 1
}

_saferun() {
        p="$1"
        shift
        if _checkpaths $*
        then
                read -p "Are you sure you want to do this? (y/n) " r && [ "$r" = "y" ]  && $p $*
        else
                $p $*
        fi
}

alias chown="_saferun /bin/chown"
alias chgrp="_saferun /bin/chgrp"
alias chmod="_saferun /bin/chmod"
```

You'd need to create a list of paths you want to protect in "$DANGERLIST" (/etc/dangerous.paths) which would be something like

```
/
/home
/etc.*
/usr/bin.*
/bin.*
```

Comment: This seems like it should work : )